# If iOS app is transferred to another user account then will its url gets changed?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I want to paste a link to my physical book, for this purpose i wanted to have iOS app url link.

Can anyone please tell if I transfer app from one account to another then will url get changed?

Comment: Probably it's only related to application ID. It shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone please tell if I transfer app from one account to another
>   then will url get changed?

No. It will not change. Every application published in App Store has it's own id that does not depend on developer account - `idxxxxxxxxx`

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/idxxxxxxxxx
```